# cakephp load component on fly

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to load component on fly in cakePHP
In this example, loading dynamically RequestHandler component for json response

```
public function xyz() {

    $this->components[] ='RequestHandler';
    $this->Components->load('RequestHandler');
    $this->RequestHandler->initialize($this);

    $abc = array("hello","world");
    $this->set('abc', $abc);
    $this->set('_serialize', array( 'abc'));
}
```

error generated on initialize function shows undefined.

### AMENDMENT FOR MORE CLEAR PICTURE:

```
public function xyz() {
    $this->components[] ='RequestHandler';
    $this->RequestHandler =  $this->Components->load('RequestHandler');
    $this->RequestHandler->initialize($this);

    $abc = array("hello","world");
    $this->set('abc', $abc);
    $this->set('_serialize', array( 'abc'));
}
```

I also tried

```
public function xyz() {

    $this->RequestHandler =  $this->Components->load('RequestHandler');
    $abc = array("hello","world");
    $this->set('abc', $abc);
    $this->set('_serialize', array( 'abc'));
}
```

I can't use component like this #$this->RequestHandler->getTime(); because cakephp automatic handle json respone.
When I hit just above code using http://disecake.localhost/resources/xyz.json

{"code":500,"url":"/resources/xyz.json","name":"View file "
/var/www/disecake/app/View/Resources/xyz.ctp" is missing."}

When I use

```
public $components = array( 'RequestHandler');
```

in my cotroller than output

```
{"abc":["hello","world"]}
```

I think now question is more clear.

Comment: _"error generated on initialize function shows undefined. Thanks"_ You're welcome. Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): no thanks in questions

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - FAQ is no longer among us. We now have a "Help Center".

Comment: Can you please edit the question and use the clipboard to copy and paste the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 13):

There is literally a section in the CakePHP book called "Loading Components on the fly".

**CakePHP 2.x:**

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#loading-components-on-the-fly

**CakePHP 3.x:**

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#loading-components-on-the-fly

(and it's done different than how you're attempting)

Comment: You are right about document. But my dear friend this document does not work as expected. In my case I want json response and I follow your given document instruction it shows related view "xyz.ctp" is not present. More over if I load RequestHandler component by define in top of controller it gives right output. I think you got my problem.

Comment: Please notice in your given document and my code that in your document OneTimer is used  $this->OneTimer->getTime();  but in my case cakePHP use that component automatically for output.

Comment: @AmitKumarSharma Your question is how to "load component on fly", not "how to return JSON data". If you have trouble with JSON, please ask a new, more related question.

Comment: I can manually return data by using $this->response. But I want to do with component and that component need to be on fly because only one function of my controller will use this component

Comment: @AmitKumarSharma - right.  Which is why you should follow the instructions in the CakePHP book per my answer/link.

Comment: I am following CakePHP book but I found nowhere how to load RequestHandler component on fly.

Comment: Hint: Read the link I sent, and change "OneTimer" to "RequestHandler".  It's not likely that the book will ever list out exactly how to load every single component - usually they'll show you how and assume you can figure out how to rename it if you want a different component.

Comment: Honestly though, it sounds like you're loading it fine (now that you've revised the question).  The error is likely something else that will require a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I can complete my task with different ways. But I just wanted to know how this specific problem can be solved.